# Can't use function return value in write context Php Using $_Session

Tags: php, mysql, session, authentication

I'm working on a login functionality for a site I'm working on, I'm trying to use the session method but I keep getting an error "Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context." Any ideas?

```php
<?php
            $db_name="name"; // Database name 
            // Connect to server and select databse.
            mysql_connect("xxxxxxx","xxxx","xxxxxx")or die("cannot connect"); 
            mysql_select_db($db_name)or die("cannot select DB");
            // username and password sent from form 
            $username=$_POST['username']; 
            $password=$_POST['password']; 

            // To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
            $myusername = stripslashes($username);
            $mypassword = stripslashes($password);
            $myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
            $mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($password);
            $sql1="SELECT * FROM `professionals` WHERE username='$username'";
            $sql2="SELECT * FROM `professionals` WHERE password='$password'";
            $result1=mysql_query($sql1);
            $result2=mysql_query($sql2);

            // Mysql_num_row is counting table row
            $count=mysql_num_rows($result1);

            // If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
            if($count==1){
                $_SESSION("username")=$result1;
                $_SESSION_("password")=$result2; 
                header("location:Success.html");
            }
            else {
                echo "Wrong Username or Password";
                header("location:Failed.html");
            }
        ?><?php
            $db_name="name"; // Database name 

            // Connect to server and select databse.
            mysql_connect("xxxxxxx","xxxx","xxxxxx")or die("cannot connect"); 
            mysql_select_db($db_name)or die("cannot select DB");
            // username and password sent from form 
            $username=$_POST['username']; 
            $password=$_POST['password']; 

            // To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
            $myusername = stripslashes($username);
            $mypassword = stripslashes($password);
            $myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
            $mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($password);
            $sql1="SELECT * FROM `professionals` WHERE username='$username'";
            $sql2="SELECT * FROM `professionals` WHERE password='$password'";
            $result1=mysql_query($sql1);
            $result2=mysql_query($sql2);

            // Mysql_num_row is counting table row
            $count=mysql_num_rows($result1);

            // If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
            if($count==1){ //Write Username and Password goes to page
                $_SESSION("username")=$result1;
                $_SESSION_("password")=$result2; 
                header("location:Success.html");
            }
            else {
                echo "Wrong Username or Password"; //Wrong Password goes to error page
                header("location:Failed.html");
            }
        ?>
```

Comment: Another thing, you shouldn't store your password in a session.

Comment: Is session_start();
on the first line of your page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$_SESSION` is an array, not a function. You try to use it as the latter here:

```
$_SESSION("username")=$result1;
$_SESSION_("password")=$result2;
```

You need to update your code as follows:

```
$_SESSION["username"] = $result1;
$_SESSION["password"] = $result2;
```

There are also numerous other errors with your code:

1. `mysql_*()` functions are now deprecated. You should consider
   upgrading your code to utilise [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).
2. I couldn't see any call to [`session_start()`](https://www.php.net/session_start) in your code. This is
   required when you wish to work with a user's session.

Comment: Thank you sir, the php now works fine! I didn't know that mysql_() functions were depreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely the issue

```
$_SESSION("username")=$result1;
$_SESSION_("password")=$result2;
```

Should be

```
$_SESSION["username"] = $result1;
$_SESSION["password"] = $result2;
```